# Choose which data to display on Highcharts

Tags: angular, highcharts

So the normal approach i am using for loading a CSV into Hicharts with Angular would be as following:

```
 export class OutputGraphComponent implements OnInit {
  public options: any = {
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
  },
  data: {
      csvURL: path.to.file
  },
  title: {
      text: window.location.origin 
  },
  yAxis: {
      title: {
          text: 'Units'
      }
  }
  }
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(){
    Highcharts.chart('container', this.options);
  }
}
```

Now, what i'd like to do would be choosing a file with for example an html form like this and then using it in the Graph.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="file">Choose File</label>
  <input type="file"
         id="file"
         (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
</div>
```

Is there any possibility to doing this without reloading the site? and if not, how else could I manage to choose which file i want to load into Highcharts on the web-application?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you use `highcharts-angular` official Highcharts wrapper for Angular. It can be downloaded here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

Now, check the example with updating CSV data without relading the page. It can be done by updating the `chartOptions.data.csv` dataset.

- https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-f14bh

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.csv